# Obtaining an Apache POI XSSFRichTextString from a textbox

Tags: java, apache-poi

How do I get an XSSFRichTextString from an Textbox in an excel spreadsheet using POI?

The setText() method is overloaded to set either a  String or XSSFRichTextString but the getText() method only returns a String.

My approaches were as follows:-

1. Change just the text in the textbox but leave the formatting unchanged. I was hoping to get the string and simply change the text but there seems to be no setText method in XSSFRichTextString. It appears that you set the text in the constructor then apply formatting using methods. Using this does put the text in the textbox but it loses all formatting.
2. Extract the entire XSSFRichTextString, extract the Formatting, create a new RTS with the new text and apply the formatting. The problem is that while there is a setFont(Font object) method the getFont() returns only a short so I cannot seem to get the Font object and change it.

3 My last option is to set the plain text in the Textbox and then programmatically set all the font and formatting elements but this means burying the formatting in the Java code which means re-coding if the user needs to tweak the format instead of just using Excel.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why not [grab the paragraphs that make up the text in the textbox](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFSimpleShape.html#getTextParagraphs--) then get the formatted text off those?

Comment: @Gagravarr. Thanks for the help. Unfortunately it will not allow me to take an existing textRun and just change the text however it does have a lot more access to the formatting. I will just have to build a formatter class that reads the formatting from the existing Text Run make a new Text Run, add the text and then reapply the formatting. Fiddly but it should be possible.
Thanks again

Comment: Just go from the textbox to the paragraph to the text runs (everything in a run has the same formatting), then change the text on the run(s) you need to. Formatting should be unchanged

Comment: Perfect!!! It works perfectly now.
Thanks for your help.
If you want to add your response as an answer I am happy to upvote and accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Promoting some comments to an answer

You can't get a `RichTextString` from an Excel textbox. The storage model for formatted text in a textbox was changed from that in plain cells, mostly it seems to support extra features and kinds of formatting. Textbox text is a bit more Word-like in how it's structured / stored

However, there's good news - you can do what you want, and change some specific text in a textbox without changing the formatting!

Firstly, from your [XSSFTextBox](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFTextBox.html), call [getTextParagraphs()](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFSimpleShape.html#getTextParagraphs--) to get the [paragraphs](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFTextParagraph.html)

Next, call [getTextRuns()](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFTextParagraph.html#getTextRuns--) to get the individual runs of text sharing the same formatting. Search through those until you find the one(s) containing the text you want to change. Finally, call [XSSFTextRun.setText(String)](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFTextRun.html#setText-java.lang.String-) to change the text of that run. The formatting will be unchanged